# PG::UndefinedColumn error for polymorphic assoc (only in controller, works in console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a polymorphic association that works fine in the rails console, but won't work when called from a controller no matter how I structure it.

The basic code:

```
# in property.rb

has_many :property_contacts, as: :property_contactable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :contacts, through: :property_contacts

# in property_contact.rb

belongs_to :contact, optional: true
belongs_to :property_contactable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

# in properties_controller.rb

def show
  @property = Property.find(params[:id])
end

# in schema.rb

create_table "property_contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "property_id" # old, before polymorphic relationship added, will remove after data migration
  t.bigint "contact_id"
  t.string "property_contactable_type"
  t.bigint "property_contactable_id"
  # ...
end

# and output from psql, just to show that there doesn't appear to be any disconnect between the schema and postgres itself

# project_name_development=# \d property_contacts
#                                                  Table "public.property_contacts"
#           Column           |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                    
# ---------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
#  property_id               | bigint                         |           |          | 
#  contact_id                | bigint                         |           |          | 
# # ...
#  property_contactable_type | character varying              |           |          | 
#  property_contactable_id   | bigint                         |           |          |
```

In a view, if I call `@property.property_contacts`, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column property_contacts.property_contactable_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...operty_contacts".* FROM "property_contacts" WHERE "property_...
                                                             ^:
```

If I force the query to run in the controller itself (using something like `@property_contacts = @property.property_contacts.load`), then
I get the same error pointing to that line in the controller.

If I omit the `property_contactable_id` from the query and build a query based on just the `property_contactable_type` column, I get an error saying that the `property_contactable_type` column doesn't exist either.

If I try to bypass the associations and build a query directly, like this, I get the same error:

```
# in controller:

@property = Property.find(params[:id])
@property_contacts = PropertyContact.for(@property)

# in property_contact.rb

  def self.for(property)
    # tried both versions, same result
    # where("property_contactable_id = ? AND property_contactable_type LIKE ?", property.id, property.class.name)
    # where("property_contacts.property_contactable_id = ? AND property_contacts.property_contactable_type LIKE ?", property.id, property.class.name)
  end
```

HOWEVER, all of these run just fine when I run them from the rails console, ex:

```
property = Property.find(123)
# both versions work
property_contacts = property.property_contacts
property_contacts = PropertyContact.for(property)
```

If I call `to_sql` on the queries, I get slightly different output from the call in the controller vs in the console:

```
# from console:
"SELECT \"property_contacts\".* FROM \"property_contacts\" WHERE \"property_contacts\".\"property_contactable_id\" = 4675010 AND \"property_contacts\".\"property_contactable_type\" = 'Property'" 
# from controller:
"SELECT \"property_contacts\".* FROM \"property_contacts\" WHERE (property_contacts.property_contactable_id = 4675010 AND property_contacts.property_contactable_type = 'Property')"
```

I tried running raw sql versions of these queries in my controller and get the same error.  Some of the different variations I tried:

```
sql = "SELECT \"property_contacts\".* FROM \"property_contacts\" WHERE \"property_contacts\".\"property_contactable_id\" = #{@property.id} AND \"property_contacts\".\"property_contactable_type\" = 'Property'"
sql = "SELECT property_contacts.* FROM property_contacts WHERE property_contacts.property_contactable_id = #{@property.id} AND property_contacts.property_contactable_type = '#{@property.class.name}' ORDER BY property_contacts.created_at desc"
sql = "SELECT property_contacts.* FROM property_contacts WHERE property_contactable_id = #{@property.id} AND property_contactable_type = '#{@property.class.name}'"
sql = "SELECT property_contacts.* FROM property_contacts WHERE property_contacts.property_contactable_type = '#{@property.class.name}' ORDER BY property_contacts.created_at desc"
sql = "SELECT \"property_contacts\".* FROM \"property_contacts\" WHERE \"property_contacts\".\"property_contactable_id\" = 4675010 AND \"property_contacts\".\"property_contactable_type\" = 'Property'"

@property_contacts = PropertyContact.find_by_sql(sql)
@property_contacts = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or give me suggestions of anything else I could try?

Comment: Make sure the records in `proptery_contacts` set the property_contactable_type correctly.  If it is NULL, there can be problems.  Since you migrated this from `property_id` that is a possibility.

Comment: @MarlinPierce Thanks, that is a good suggestion, and it was one of the things I was keeping an eye on.  It ended up being an issue with an existing multi-tenancy module that switched between different schema versions, so I was basically interacting with two different versions of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue- the application I'm working on came with a hand-rolled multi-tenancy module, and the migration I created was only migrating the public schema. It's not used very often throughout the app so it's easy to forget that it's there. I was interacting with the public schema through the console, but a specific tenant's schema (which didn't have the new columns I added) through the web server.